# Variável File com saída [Ljava.lang.String;@

Tags: java

Quando faço um Sysout da minha variavel do tipo File, me aparece essa saída:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3e92957f
```

E meu sysout é assim:

```
System.out.println(entrada.getPath() + " " + saida.getPath());
```

O engraçado é que no `saida.getPath()` a saída é exatamente o que eu quero. Alguém sabe o porque?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o erro, usando o método `instanceof` no objeto, consegui transformar em String certinho. Pra quem tiver a mesma dúvida, eis o código:

```
for (Object obj : objArr) {
     if (objeto instanceof String[]) {
     String[] strArray = (String[]) objeto;
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
    }
}
```